# How to use drop down or radio button to select textbox and submit different MySQL query?

Tags: php, mysql

I have five textboxes on the same webpage for five different MySQL queries. I need this because the text in the textbox is different and depend on the MySQL query that I need to do.
May I use a drop down menu or radio button to select different textbox and so to select different MySQL query to execute?

Here is my code:

```
<table border="1" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
    <tr>
        <td align="left">Query per office</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table>
                <form method="post" action="drawsiti_query_output.php">
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" name="ufficio" size="20"> 
                        </td>
                        <td align="right"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Esegui"></td>
                    </tr>
                </form>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<p></p>

<table border="1" bgcolor="#6e00ff">
    <tr>
        <td align="left">Query per nome</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table>
                <form method="post" action="drawsiti_query_output_nomesito.php">
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" name="nomesito" size="20"> 
                        </td>
                        <td align="right"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Esegui"></td>
                    </tr>
                </form>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<p></p>

<table border="1" bgcolor="#ff0000">
    <tr>
        <td align="left">Query per codice 2g</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table>
                <form method="post" action="drawsiti_query_output_2g.php">
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" name="codice2g" size="20"> 
                        </td>
                        <td align="right"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Esegui"></td>
                    </tr>
                </form>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<p></p>
<table border="1" bgcolor="#00c2ff">
    <tr>
        <td align="left">Query per codice 3g</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table>
                <form method="post" action="drawsiti_query_output_3g.php">
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" name="codice3g" size="20"> 
                        </td>
                        <td align="right"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Esegui"></td>
                    </tr>
                </form>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<p></p>
<table border="1" bgcolor="#06fc00">
    <tr>
        <td align="left">Query per codice 4g</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table>
                <form method="post" action="drawsiti_query_output_4g.php">
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" name="codice4g" size="20"> 
                        </td>
                        <td align="right"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Esegui"></td>
                    </tr>
                </form>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<p></p>
<table border="1" bgcolor="#f100ff">
    <tr>
        <td align="left">Query per office -> output cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table>
                <form method="post" action="drawsiti_query_output_cell.php">
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" name="ufficio" size="20"> 
                        </td>
                        <td align="right"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Esegui"></td>
                    </tr>
                </form>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Why is this tagged with c# ?

Comment: Im sorry, your question is not entirely clear to me, what would you want to accomplish using these radiobuttons / dropdown menu? You already have submit input fields so in my mind you could just click the appropiate submit button.

Also don't just tag your question with popular tags just to get more attention

Comment: I'm sorry for the abuse of tag! I have just delete the not necessary ones.

Comment: Yes, I have five textbox and five submit button. For every textbox I have one submit button that redirect to a .php page that contain the mysql query. The text in textbox is passed via POST to the mysql query. I would like to have one textbox and one submit query but i would like to switch between the mysql query with radiobutton or dropdown menu.

Answer (score 0):

You can change input name or form action by select. (or together)

```
<select>
    <option value="ufficio">ufficio</option>
    ..
    </select>
<input type="text" id="inp" name=""/>

<script>
$('select').change(function(){
    $('#inp').attr('name', $(this).val());
});
</script>
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for reply. I need also a submit button such as <input type="submit" value="Submit"> and I need to switch between mysql query while select from dropdown menu. How can i do it?